# parse error no for each

Tags: php

Não sei porque esse *parse error* no meu `foreach`. Segue o código :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["submit"])){

}

$form =

foreach ($_GET["cimc"] as $form) {
    $peso ==  $_GET['peso'];
    $altura == $_GET['altura'];

    if (isset($peso)) {
        $imc = ($peso /( $altura * $altura));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Saudações, terráqueo. O que seria esse `$form = ` perdido no seu código?

Comment: saudações, esse $form = no caso foi sem querer, ja retirei e continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Por favor, faça o [tour] e leia o guia de [ask]. Busque [edit] a pergunta e adicionar exatamente qual é a mensagem de erro. Exceto você ter utilizado `==` para atribuição ao invés de `=`, não consegui reproduzir o "parser error" que citou.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /var/www/html/main/biblioteca/imc.php on line 31 seria esse o erro

Comment: Isso daria com o `$form` ali. Se tirou, não tem porque dar o erro ainda.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: cimc in /var/www/html/main/biblioteca/imc.php on line 31

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/main/biblioteca/imc.php on line 31
?>

Answer (score 0):

Experimente verificar a existência de todas a variáveis e o seu tipo

```
 if(isset($_GET["cimc"]) && is_array($_GET["cimc"])){
        foreach ($_GET["cimc"] as $form) {
            if(isset($_GET['peso']) && isset($_GET['altura'])) {
                $imc = ($_GET['peso'] /( $_GET['altura'] * $_GET['altura']));
            }else{
                echo "Não temos: ";
                echo (isset($_GET['peso'])) ? "a altura": "o peso";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo (isset($_GET["cimc"])) ? '':'Não temos $_GET["cimc"]';
        echo (is_array($_GET["cimc"])) ? '':'$_GET["cimc"] Não é array';
    }
```